# find all the possible differences of the elements of a list

Tags: algorithm, diff

I am trying to find all the possible differences between the elements of one list.

For example:

```
x=[1,4,10,17,20,35].
```

I would like to have as an answer an array:

```
y=[3, 9, 16, 19, 34, 3, 6, 13, 16, 31, 9, 6, 7, 10, 25, 16, 13, 10, 3, 18, 19, 16, 10, 3, 15, 34, 31, 25, 18, 15]
```

corresponding to

```
[1-4, 1-10, 1-17, 1-20, 1-35, 4-1, 4-10, 4-17, ....]
```

I have tried to do that with diff, but I only get the difference of two consecutive numbers. and I do not really know how to compute it in a loop.

Can you please help?

Comment: you need 2 loops: i=0->n-2, and j=i+1->n-1. however, we're not here to write the code for you, and since you haven't specified a language, we CAN'T anyways.

Comment: In Python a simple list comprehension will get you it in a single line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Python 1-liner:

```
>>> [abs(a - b) for i,a in enumerate(x) for j,b in enumerate(x) if i != j]
[3, 9, 16, 19, 34, 3, 6, 13, 16, 31, 9, 6, 7, 10, 25, 16, 13, 7, 3, 18, 19, 16, 10, 3, 15, 34, 31, 25, 18, 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing in Java, it is as simple as this:

```
List<Integer> diff = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<list.size(); j++) {
        if(i != j)
            diff.add(Math.abs(list.get(i) - list.get(j)));
    }
}
```

Comment: OP doesn't seem to want the zeros on the diagonal

Comment: You are not checking if you are operating with the same numbers/index

Answer (score 0):

A solution written in python

```
elements = [1,4,10,17,20,35]
differences = []
for i , element in enumerate(elements):
    for j, element2 in enumerate(elements):
        if i != j:
            differences.append( abs(element - element2) )
```